# How can I convert a column variable into a mutually exclusive case row?

Tags: r

Apologies for title, edits for clarity welcome. I have some table that looks like this, with multiple cases and a variable `all` for each case, as well as a variable `B2`. The cases have a hierarchy such that here `B` means all `B` that are not `A`, so that `all` sums to 100. I want to include an additional case `B2` between `B` and `C` that follows this pattern.

```r
library(tidyverse)
tbl <- tribble(
  ~case, ~all, ~B2,
  "A", 10, 5,
  "B", 20, 7,
  "C", 30, 10,
  "D", 40, 15
)
```

Here is the desired output. Note that the value for the case `B2` is 25, which is 10 + 15 from the table above. Those values have been correspondingly subtracted from the `C` and `D` cases.

```r
tbl_out <- tribble(
  ~case, ~all,
  "A", 10,
  "B", 20,
  "B2", 25,
  "C", 20,
  "D", 25,
)
```

Here is my very messy attempt at getting the desired result. I feel there should be some way to better encode the "hierarchy" in the cases (by sorting?), instead of having to manually specify `preceding` and bind tables together. Any suggestions?

```r
tbl %>%
  mutate(
    preceding = case %in% c("A", "B"),
    new_vals = if_else(preceding, all, all - B2)
  ) %>%
  bind_rows(
    group_by(., preceding) %>%
      summarise(case = "B2", new_vals = sum(B2))
  ) %>%
  filter(!is.na(B2) | preceding == FALSE) %>%
  select(case, new_vals) %>%
  arrange(case)
#> # A tibble: 5 x 2
#>   case  new_vals
#>   <chr>    <dbl>
#> 1 A           10
#> 2 B           20
#> 3 B2          25
#> 4 C           20
#> 5 D           25
```

<sup>Created on 2019-03-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Do the values `5` and `7` in your original table (the `A` and `B` rows of the `B2` column) have any meaning? It looks like they are ignored...

Comment: This process and data structure seems really bizarre... I think I would only make minor changes to the code you have.

Comment: They do mean something but I am not counting them as in those cases. It's like "if it is A, i want to count it as A, then if it is B, count it as B (implicitly unless it is A)." Perhaps I will try and make an example with raw data to show how I end up here.